# To get the count of key-value occurrence for JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json array as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "57833bf8cb3099a383e8e2af"
    },
    "Name": "3GBWS",
    "Version": "QV3.2",
    "Type": "FQGA",
    "SerialNO": "L1D73708884",
    "Location": "TEXAS"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"
    },
    "Name": "3GBTW",
    "Version": "WN6.0",
    "Type": "FQGW",
    "SerialNO": "O1143734584",
    "Location": "OHIO"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"
    },
    "Name": "TEXAS",
    "Version": "AS1.0",
    "Type": "FWQA",
    "SerialNO": "DH783708884",
    "Location": "NY"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"
    },
    "Name": "3GLTS",
    "Version": "WE9.0",
    "Type": "FQGW",
    "SerialNO": "L0943708884",
    "Location": "TEXAS"
  }
]
```

My aim is to get output as Texas=2 .

Here I need to get the occurrence of "TEXAS" only under the key "Location".
Is there any way to compare the key-value pair in java? I tried with `int location = Collections.frequency(json_string, "TEXAS");` , but this wont consider the key "Location". 
Please help.

Comment: Are you using a JSON library?

Comment: @Flown: I didn't get your query.. I am fetching the json data from mongodb

Comment: How do you parse your JSON string?

Comment: This is my parsing code :

`JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String AssetNo = jobj.getString("AssetNo");
            String SerialNO = jobj.getString("SerialNO");
            String Location = jobj.getString("Location");
return " "+"AssetNo" + ":" +"  "  +AssetNo + "\n" + " "+"SerialNO" + ":" +"  "  +SerialNO + "\n" + " "+"Location" + ":" +"  "  +Location; `

Comment: My initial question was: which JSON library are you using?

Comment: @Flown I am using org.json library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided your JSON library I'm assuming `org.json`.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    String json = "[\r\n" + 
        "  {\r\n" + 
        "    \"_id\": {\r\n" + 
        "      \"$oid\": \"57833bf8cb3099a383e8e2af\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"Name\": \"3GBWS\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Version\": \"QV3.2\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Type\": \"FQGA\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"SerialNO\": \"L1D73708884\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Location\": \"TEXAS\"\r\n" + 
        "  },\r\n" + 
        "  {\r\n" + 
        "    \"_id\": {\r\n" + 
        "      \"$oid\": \"5784818bcb30b4918964b50f\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"Name\": \"3GBTW\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Version\": \"WN6.0\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Type\": \"FQGW\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"SerialNO\": \"O1143734584\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Location\": \"OHIO\"\r\n" + 
        "  },\r\n" + 
        "  {\r\n" + 
        "    \"_id\": {\r\n" + 
        "      \"$oid\": \"5784818bcb30b4918964b50f\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"Name\": \"TEXAS\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Version\": \"AS1.0\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Type\": \"FWQA\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"SerialNO\": \"DH783708884\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Location\": \"NY\"\r\n" + 
        "  },\r\n" + 
        "  {\r\n" + 
        "    \"_id\": {\r\n" + 
        "      \"$oid\": \"5784818bcb30b4918964b50f\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"Name\": \"3GLTS\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Version\": \"WE9.0\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Type\": \"FQGW\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"SerialNO\": \"L0943708884\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"Location\": \"TEXAS\"\r\n" + 
        "  }\r\n" + 
        "]";
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject element = array.getJSONObject(i);
      String location = element.getString("Location");
      if(location.equals("TEXAS")) {
        count ++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("TEXAS=" + count);
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked for my code..Now it is comparing the whole key-value pair..Thanks for your help @Flown

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you generate your POJO classes with an online tool (e.g. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then you can simply manipulate them anyway you want. For example with a static method:

```
public static int countLocationOccurrences(List<YourClass> collections, String location) {
    int count = 0;
    for(YourClass item : collections) {
        if (item.getLocation().equals(location)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter some values:

```
locations = j.map(elem => elem.Location) // j is the array
```

after this you well have an array with the locations, and you can do with it as you like.